# Bubbles on the Noodle surface

Tags: frying, food-science, noodles

I observe lots of bubbles on the noodle surface after frying. What causes this and how can I control it?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What kind of noodles are they? How are you frying them?

Comment: Why do you want to control it? It sounds to me like you are just getting the shape of your noodles changed. It shouldn't affect taste much, and would be hard to change unless you accept much larger changes in taste and texture. It is basic physics that water (within the noodle) will turn to steam and expand a lot when suddenly heated in the oil.

Answer (score 2):

Deep frying noodles is likely to create bubbles, depending on exactly how the dough was formed; this is normal and expected.  You see this on almost all battered fried foods.

The actual mechanism is that the heat of the oil partially sets the starches on the surface of the noodle fairly quickly, creating an a barrier to the further escape of water or steam.  As the water under the surface converts to steam from the heat of frying, it expands dramatically (about 1,700 times the volume of the water), but has no where to go.  The pressure created from the steam pushes out the surface noodle, creating a bubble.

As the frying continues, the starches completely set, making the bubble surface crispy and brittle.

I don't think there is a simple method to control this process.  You could try frying at a slightly lower temperature, which would slow the process down, and perhaps allow more steam to escape rather than create bubbles, but I haven't tried this, and am not confident that it would work.

Comment: If the OP's noodles are especially wet, maybe it'd help to dry out the noodles, or at least the surface, a bit first?